# What is a good book for multivariate stochastic processes?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I'm looking for a good book that introduces (preferred without measure-theoretic proofs though that may have to do) multivariate stochastic processes. So suppose you have $\{\mathbf{X}_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}_0^\infty\}$ where $\mathbf{X}_n \in \Re^k$ or $\in \mathfrak{C}^k$. I want a book that discusses things like power spectrums, optimal linear prediction, transfer of a power spectrum through a linear system (with a matrix transfer function), etc. in the context of this vector-valued stochastic process.

Every reference I check in the library or find online is for scalar stochastic processes mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Spectral Analysis and Its Applications 1968 by G. M. Jenkins and D. G. Watts has all the information I requested. Looks like works from the 60s can often trump tons others from 2000s.